# Error loading function from file in GHCi

Tags: macos, haskell, load, ghci

I'm completely new to Haskell. To grasp the basics I've started working through 'Learn you a Haskell for Great Good'. I'm stuck on the simple matter of loading a function from a file.

The file is called `baby.hs` and contains the function

```
doubleMe x = x + x
```

and nothing else. I've saved it in `/Users/me`.

Typing `:load baby` into GHCi, I get the following error:

> target `baby' is not a module name or a source file.

I'm working on a Mac and I created my `baby.hs` file using TextEdit set to produce a plain text/UTF-8 file. I think my home directory is `/Users/me` although I'm not sure how to check this from GHCi, it is from when I check from bash before running GHCi.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @clintm suggests, first fix your doubleMe function. What you have will give errors --- but not the errors you're reporting.

The simplest way to get ghci to find your file is to make sure you start ghci from the same directory your file is saved in. Open a terminal window, and type

```
cd /Users/me
ls
```

`ls` lists the contents of the current directory; you should see your file. If you do, great! Type `ghci` at the bash prompt, and `:load baby` should work. If not, you haven't saved your file where you think you have. Go back to TextEdit or use Spotlight to see where you've really put it.

Comment: thank you, typing ls showed the problem: My file was really called baby.hs.txt! TextEdit seems to add a .txt suffix even if you overwrite the extension with .hs and Finder doesn't display the .txt just the .hs. It does seem to display .txt for normal textEdit files so I'm guessing it does something like display the first .suffix and hide any others.

Comment: @Alec: Ouch.  Find a better editor.  Even if you don't want to take the time to learn one of the classic workhorses (vim or emacs), there's tons of good text editors for OSX.  Syntax highlighting is a must.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the module line.  The first line of baby.hs should be

```
module Baby where
```

As far as `doubleMe` is concerned, you are missing declaring `x` as an argument to the function.

```
doubleMe x = x + x
```

Otherwise, your function doesn't know what `x` is.

Comment: The module line is good practice, but it's not necessary for this simple a case. It should work without it.

Comment: apologies the doubleMe error was a typo in the question. The problem was that the file was really called  baby.hs.txt but I didn't spot that as Finder hide the .txt part for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the complete path, for example:

```
:load /Users/me/baby.hs
```

You should also be able to use relative paths. Try navigating to the directory that `baby.hs` is in first:

```
% cd /Users/me
% ghci
GHCi blah blah blah
Prelude> :load baby.hs
```

When you get that working, then try leaving off the `.hs`. I'm not 100% sure under what circumstances that works.

Comment: You can give `:load` a filename (always including the trailing `.hs` or `.lhs`) or a module name (which must start with a capital letter).

Comment: @dave4420: You can omit the trailing `.hs` from file names. GHCi is smart enough to try a few variants.

Comment: thanks. Found the problem in the end, my file was really called  baby.hs.txt, although Finder hides the .txt

Answer (score 0):

@Alec: "The problem was that the file was really called baby.hs.txt but I didn't spot that as Finder hide the .txt part for some reason."

You can work around this in TextEdit...

- select your baby.hs.txt file
- two-finger tap it to pop up the context menu
- select Get Info to open the file's Info dialog
- enter baby.hs in the Name & Extension area
- close the Info dialog
- another dialog asks if you really want the .hs extension
- confirm that you do and you're good-to-go

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the text file with GHCi then type your command and it works